# Safari created objects return null values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I'm using Angular clients and send data from MVC 4.5 server side. 
I'm sending objects to the client using Signalr. It works great in all browsers except from Safari 5.17 on a Windows 10.

I'm not using Json serialize, because it is not yet in Signalr.

The objects values looks like this:

```
Favorite: false
Id: null
Internal: false
LastAction: "0001-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
```

Anyone have a good suggestion to solve this?

Comment: 1 out of 10 times, the object contains values.